# What is the auto-save point in Central Yharnam?

Tags: ps4, bloodborne

I just started Bloodborne and am having a difficult time getting past the mob of assailants in Central Yharnam.

How far do I have to get in this area to reach an auto-save point?  Or is there one?

Also, do I have to clear the entire mob before being able to continue in the map?

Comment: Not really an answer, your question is answered pretty well below. All I wanted to say is stick with it and work out how to pick the mob off two or three at a time. There is no problem going through that area over and over and over again. Just try to keep/recover your blood echoes and use them to level up. I spent ages on that first mob, I must've done it well over a hundred times. Also, when you tackle the bosses, summon some help to avoid frustration!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no "auto-save" points, you have to find and light lanterns to the Hunters Dream. These are more like spawn points or quick travel.

The first one is to the left after leaving the starting building, past the stage coach, and up a ladder. The ladder has to be dropped down by pulling a lever nearby.

Comment: I had found that spawn-point lantern when I entered Central Yharnam, thanks.  How far through the area is the next one?

Comment: I think the next one is revealed after defeating the first boss. You're probably better off exploring more and opening the shortcut to the boss before facing that.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, you have to beat a 1 of 2 bosses to get your 3rd (2nd if you killed the wolf (first monster) with bare hands) lantern.

However, if you are having trouble getting past the monsters what you should work on is shortcut that links the Central Yharnam lantern and the boss area. It will enable you to get to bosses without losing vials.

If you don't mind **spoilers** read ahead:

> Spoiler Just before the Cleric beast there is a door into a building on the side of the bridge you can open (and travel a bit) to reach and unlock the other gate at the lantern you have right now. If you explore that area you will find a lot more shortcuts. One the sewer paths leads to Father Gascoigne (who in my opinion is an easier boss than the Cleric beast).